# Getting rid of error in my code?

Tags: r

I am having some trouble with this code.  So far I have:

```
yes<-0
no<-0
sample<-20000
mean<-(10/12)
LowerBound<-LB
UpperBound<-UB
LB<-(mean-2)*sqrt(20/1872)
UB<-(mean+2)*sqrt(20/1872)

for(i in 1:sample){
    sample<-rbeta(10,10,2)
    LB<-(mean-2)*sqrt(20/1872) 
    UB<-(mean+2)*sqrt(20/1872)

}
```

But I am getting the error of

> Error in eval(ei, envir) : object 'LB' not found

Comment: Where you assign LB to lower bound (`LowerBound<-LB`) you haven't yet assigned a value to LB. Downvote for lack of basic effort. Please see help centre before using stackoverflow.

Comment: 2 sources are always better than 1.  Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

You have things out of order. you are defining `LowerBound` as the value of `LB` but `LB` is not defined until later as `LB<-(mean-2)*sqrt(20/1872)`

```
yes<-0
no<-0
sample<-20000
mean<-(10/12)
LB<-(mean-2)*sqrt(20/1872)
UB<-(mean+2)*sqrt(20/1872)
LowerBound<-LB
UpperBound<-UB

for(i in 1:sample){
    sample<-rbeta(10,10,2)
    LB<-(mean-2)*sqrt(20/1872) 
    UB<-(mean+2)*sqrt(20/1872)

}
```

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks Pat!

Comment: Can you mark the answer as correct?